# iOS - Objective - C Google Maps use of undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder

So I am relatively new with using Google Maps and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. As I am following [Google Maps - iOS documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#accessibility). Under the subtitle of Camera Position I have used this block of code:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)cameraPosition {
        id handler = ^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         if (error == nil) {
         GMSReverseGeocodeResult *result = response.firstResult;
         GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:cameraPosition.target];
         marker.title = result.lines[0];
         marker.snippet = result.lines[1];
         marker.map = mapView;
      }
    };
  [geocoder_ reverseGeocodeCoordinate:cameraPosition.target completionHandler:handler];
  }
```

The main problem is the last line.

```
[geocoder_ reverseGeocodeCoordinate:cameraPosition.target completionHandler:handler];
```

As Xcode gives me the following error - **"Use of undeclared identifier 'geocoder_' "**

Why is this occurring?

Comment: did you use MKReverseGeocoder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable `geocoder_`:

```
GMSGeocoder *geocoder_ = [GMSGeocoder geocoder];
```

↳ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_geocoder

Answer (score 0):

You are using undefined variable **geocoder_**, looking at naming I think Google uses instance variable defined somewhere else, that they forgot to include in sample code.

You have to define **geocoder_** in your **.m** file:

```
@implementation SomeViewController {
    GMSGeocoder *geocoder_;
}
```

and initialize **geocoder_** to **GMSGeocoder** instance, before calling any methods, like this:

```
geocoder_ = [GMSGeocoder geocoder];
```

preferrably inside *viewDidLoad()* method if you are using this code in *UIViewController* descendant.

Answer (score 0):

MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated as of iOS 5.0, so you have to use the class CLGeoCoder and a method called reverseGeocodeLocation.

Luckily for you, Apple has even an example on how to achieve what you are looking for.

Look out for "Geocoding a location using CLGeocoder" in the link below:

[enter link description here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html)

I hope this helps!